# Url rewrite rule for username in nginx webserver

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

How Can I make rewrite rule for /variableusername - url www.example.com/variableusername

```
    location /staticusername {

            try_files $uri/ /admin/index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }
```

If I change /staticusername with my one username all working like I need. But When I try to login with other username surely isn't work.
So How can I rewrite my each users to /admin/index.php?q=$uri&$args ?
Thanks for any opinion

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
location / {

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;

    # rewriteRule: example.com/userName_0-9
    rewrite ^/([A-Za-z0-9_]+)$ /admin/index.php?q=$1;    
}
```